# Uninstall programmatically j2me application

Tags: java-me

Is there any way to uninstall an j2me application programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  You can guide a user to install an upgraded version instead of the existing one (by pointing to the upgraded MIDlet's JAD in a [platformRequest](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html#platformRequest(java.lang.String))), but they have to remove it on their own.

Comment: is there any way to the user download the jar file after installed into the phone?

Answer (score 2):

Sony-Ericsson feature phones have a proprietary Application Management System API that can be used to programatically uninstall an application from a MIDlet but it is only available to Sony-Ericsson partners.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same problem so I searched on Nokia forums.. I could find some Symbian C++ programs that can uninstall J2ME (as well as Symbian C++) apps.. Is it that Symbian C++ has access to System Files and J2ME does not have?